# How to surface a docker-registry secret in Rancher?

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, ecr, rancher

I am using Rancher 2.5.8 to run Kubernetes clusters. In my org, we maintain a private docker registry on AWS ECR. I know I can create registry credentials within a project (for use in one or all projects), but ECR changes the password every 12 hours and Rancher has no built in away to update the credentials. Someone came up with a convoluted way of updating the password with two container apps, but I find it much easier to use the aws cli and kubectl in the host vm to do this. I created a cron job that uses kubectl to delete and create a docker-registry secret in the cluster programmatically (there's no way to update a secret, apparently), but I can't figure out how to make that docker-registry secret visible in Rancher. Anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that the credential is created in the default project for the cluster in the Rancher UI. I was looking in the wrong place.